# Stop ASP.Net Development Server spinning up when using Azure Emulator

Tags: debugging, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am using The Azure Emulator for test deployment of an ASP.NET Web API application. When I run this I notice that the asp.net dev emulator also runs. As this does not seem to be needed, is there a way to stop it from spinning up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things to understand with Windows Azure ASP.NET Web role application:

1. When you have your Web Role set as "Startup Application" or you run ASP.NET web Role application only, you you will see the ASP.NET site runs at http:\localhost:XX this is because you are running your web application directly in IIS without any relationship with Azure Compute Emulator.
2. When you have your Windows Azure project set as "Startup Application" or you launch your Windows Azure application directly, in that case your ASP.NET web application will run within Windows Azure Compute Emulator. In this scenario the Compute Emulator will start if not running and if running then the ASP.NET web application will still run with IIS however due to virtual load balancer scenario you will see the ASP.NET web application is running at http://127.0.0.x:XX.

So depend on how you launch your project within your solution you will see different execution. When compute Emulator is running you can open its UI to understand how your different instances are running.

Finally based on your above requirement it seems you just want to test your application in IIS only so if you just set your ASP.NET web role to "startup project" you will not see compute emulator activity.

Comment: Also, to run with Azure compute emulator, run VS with elevated privileges.